# Comparing two arrays if they have the exact same values

Tags: javascript

I have a first array of objects, inside this array there are objects each containg a members array containing an x amount of userIds
In my second array, I have an array of userIds, I want to create a function that returns true or false if and only if the two arrays have the same entries.
Heres what I have tried:

```
const compareArrays = () => {
  if (usersConvos.some(convo=> JSON.stringify(convo.members)=== JSON.stringify(membersArray)) {
   return true
  }
  else {
   return false
  }
}
```

This doesnt work  any idea?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript

Comment: doesnt solve my issue, this is just comparing to arrays

Comment: and your question is how to compare arrays if those have same values

Comment: The linked question is also comparing arrays? Using `JSON.stringify` is dependent on ordering, which may or may not be what you need, too.

Comment: @miyavmiyav Is not it would be more effective if you ask why the given answers do not solve the issue before closing a question?

Comment: If I only could close questions ;)

Comment: @DaveNewton and the accepted answer in linked question does not use `JSON.stringify()` but hey lets just type random stuff

Comment: @miyavmiyav What? I didn't say it did.